# How to add stickyness to fullscreen ScrollableRow elements with Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-scrollable-tabs, android-jetpack-compose-row

I have a `ScrollableRow` with lets say 5 fullscreen composables.

```
ScrollableRow(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    scrollState = scrollState) {
        myData.items.forEachIndexed{ index, pageItem ->
            showPage(pageItem)
        }
}
```

Everything is shown so far, but when I swipe left/right it stops exactly on the position, where I stopped swiping:
[image]
As you can see and imagne, almost everytime it stops between two of these full screen composables.

I'd rather have a kind of stickyness and show full pages for **each single left/right swipe** as pictured here:
[image]

So obviously, here in the second picture with third page showing:

- when I swipe one time left, I want to see full screen page 4, only
- when I swipe one time right, I want to see full screen page 2, only

I bet there is a mechanism for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HorizontalPager** will suit you. Check [Accompanist Pager layouts](https://google.github.io/accompanist/pager/)